# ASP.Net QueryString Sort Parameter with Dojo JsonRest Memory Store

Tags: asp.net, dojo, dojo.gridx

I have made a gridx grid that uses a JsonRest Memory store from the dojo framework
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html

the issue is  I do not know how to pull out the sort parameter from the query string.

The url being formatted from the JsonRest call is

```
/admin/sales?sort(+DealershipName)
```

using  the following statement gives me a null error

```
String sort = Request.QueryString["sort"].ToString();
```

Looking at the debugger  I see the following (I need more rep to post images :( )

ok I can see that the following variables hold this value.

```
Request.QueryString =   {sort(+DealershipName)}
type :     System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection         
{System.Web.HttpValueCollection}
```

but the array is null.

I'm thinking I can do two thing.  Parse the string myself  or   overload the dojo JsonRest Memory store.        Parsing the string seems easier but if anyone has any idea or knows any libraries that can help me out. I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo/store/JsonRest` has a `sortParam` property that you can set to the name of a standard query parameter to use instead of `sort(...)` (which it uses by default to avoid colliding with any standard query parameters).

For example, adding `sortParam: 'sort'` to the properties passed to the `JsonRest` constructor will result in the query string including `sort=+DealershipName` instead.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#sorting

If the `+` also presents a problem, you can also override `ascendingPrefix` to be an empty string (`''`).  Note that descending sort will still be indicated by a leading `-` (controllable via `descendingPrefix`).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm not sure how I missed that.